# Division throwing "expression in SELECT list no valid."

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

In our database we have some tables that use a decimal date format along these lines: yyyymmdd, all as one big decimal (ie, today would be 20130225).  I'm trying to create an SQL query that pulls things back in monthly buckets.  From my research it seems the best approach is to just divide the number by 100 to cut off the days on the far right (20130225/100 equals 201302 if the remainder is removed.)

I can't seem to figure out how to make it function.  I started by using something like `(INVOICE_DATE/100) As "INVOICE_MONTH"` in both my Select and Group by.  When that didn't work I reduced the Group by to `"INVOICE_MONTH"` and then to `(INVOICE_DATE/100)`, neither of which worked.  So I reduced the Select and Group by to just `INVOICE_DATE/100` which still doesn't seem to be working.

Here's my code at current (with a couple small redactions)

```
Select  Count(COMPETITOR_NAME) as "STORE COUNT",
    COMPETITOR_NAME,
    INVOICE_DATE/100,
    CUSTOMER_NUMBER,   
    OVERRIDE_TYPE,
    Sum (QTY_SOLD) as "Quantity Sold",
    Sum (EXT_ORIGINAL_PRICE) as "Sum Original Price", 
    Sum (EXT_OVERRIDE_PRICE) as "Sum Override Price", 
    Sum (EXT_VARIANCE) As "Sum Variance",
    Sum (INTERNAL_COST) as "Internal Cost"
From    DA*****.DW*******.PRCOVRWK
Where   INVOICE_DATE/100 between 201002 and 201302
Group By    ROLLUP(COMPETITOR_NAME,
    INVOICE_DATE/100),
    OVERRIDE_TYPE,
    CUSTOMER_NUMBER
Order By    OVERRIDE_TYPE,
    COMPETITOR_NAME,
    INVOICE_DATE,
    CUSTOMER_NUMBER
```

I can't help but wonder if my Where statement is causing problems as well.  At first I was just using `Where INVOICE_DATE between 20100225 and 20130225`, but I thought perhaps it needed to use the same thing as was in the Select statement?  (Yeah, I'm kinda stretching at this point.)  I've been doing my best to follow the documentation on IBMs website, but I must be reading it wrong as it doesn't seem to function as expected.

At any rate.  The basic need is to be able to pull the information back in monthly buckets.  So, however that might be accomplished is acceptable if you know another approach.  My hope is to be able to just use decimal division to pull up the year/date combo and using that in the Group By to get the results I need.

PS- We are using v5,1 of DB2 for i.

Comment: `month(Invoice_Date)` doesn't extract just the month? if not then can you confirm what the datatype is for the Field?

Comment: Which expression in the select list is it complaining about? (Remove them one by one until it works)

Comment: @xQbert The date is contained as a decimal.  I thought we couldn't use date arithmetic on a decimal?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Fairly certain it's the INVOICE_DATE/100 because it worked fin until I added the division.

Comment: @JayCarr You're right can't use date functions on Decimal.  I was a bit confused on the original post showing decimal date format Since most DBs store dates as numbers under the covers, I didn't know if the issue was with how the date was being extracted, or if you really meant that the field was defined as a `Number (8,0)`

Comment: @xQbert yeah, really wish it was a date but I don't make these tables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be fairly simple, actually.  The problem was that I didn't have the division properly listed in the `Order By`.  It doesn't seem like that should have mattered, but once I did that the whole thing worked.

I did end up with a decimal answer.  I decided to fix that by using rounding though, which seems to have gone well.  Here's the code I ended up with for the curious:

```
Select  Count(COMPETITOR_NAME) as "STORE COUNT",
    COMPETITOR_NAME,
    ROUND(INVOICE_DATE/100, 0) As "Month_Date",
    CUSTOMER_NUMBER,   
    OVERRIDE_TYPE,
    Sum (QTY_SOLD) as "Quantity Sold",
    Sum (EXT_ORIGINAL_PRICE) as "Sum Original Price", 
    Sum (EXT_OVERRIDE_PRICE) as "Sum Override Price", 
    Sum (EXT_VARIANCE) As "Sum Variance",
    Sum (INTERNAL_COST) as "Internal Cost"
From    DA******.DW*******.PRCOVRWK
Where   INVOICE_DATE > 20100201
Group By    COMPETITOR_NAME,
    ROUND(INVOICE_DATE/100, 0),
    OVERRIDE_TYPE,
    CUSTOMER_NUMBER
Order By    COMPETITOR_NAME,
    ROUND(INVOICE_DATE/100, 0),
    SUM (EXT_VARIANCE),
    CUSTOMER_NUMBER
```

So, yeah, silly as it might seem, DB2 V5,1 just really wanted me to make the statement match between the `Select`,`Group By` and `Order By`.  Well, nearly the same, you can use `As` in the `Select` but not anywhere else.

Hope this helps anyone else who seems to be having a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Decimal dates make our life more difficult than they need to be.  May I suggest using [Alan Campin's IDate functions](http://www.think400.dk/downloads.htm)?  They'll let you easily convert those decimals into SQL date data types.  Once you have that, you can extract out the year and month and do your GROUP BY on those.

Are you really on V5R1?  I didn't think ROLLUP worked that early...

Comment: lol, yeah, if it was up to me...  I keep being told we have 6,1, but all my errors say 5,1.  And yes, Rollup works.  I would also agree that decimal dates are the bane of our existence, but I have no ability to change our date formats.  All of these decisions are outside of my hands.  Thanks though :-).

Comment: You wouldn't be changing the database at all, what you'd have is a set of SQL User Defined Functions which convert the decimal 'dates' into true SQL dates for your use within SQL statements.

Comment: I probably should have been more explicit.  I only have read access to this server.  iDates documentation say I would need to save files to the iSeries, and that's not something they're going to let me do.  Is there a way to run this sort of thing on my side?

Comment: It's hard to tell from the question what 'my side' is - I thought you were running code on IBM i.  IDate is just a package for a set of SQL UDFs, and like all UDFs on any SQL database, they need to be loaded on the server.  If it were my project, I'd ask the midrange admins to load this for me.  With read-only access, you can't create your own UDF or even a stored procedure on your own; a very restrictive policy.  Sorry to hear that.

Comment: Yeah, again, sorry.  I'm just using SQuirrel to write SQL on my desktop and access the iSeries from a distance.  The sys admins don't really know me and my supervisor is reluctant to even ask if we can do things like this with the server.  It's not the best, but that's life.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Giving this one an upvote even though it's not an option for the OP. I think most people who encounter this question will be looking for something that they can do *on the IBM i*, and iDate fits the bill nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert the decimal to a date.

```
select digits(date), 
  year(date(
    substr(digits(date),1,4) concat 
    ''-'' concat 
    substr(digits(date),5,2) concat
    ''-'' concat substr(digits(date),7,2))) as year,
  month(date(
    substr(digits(date),1,4) concat 
    ''-'' concat 
    substr(digits(date),5,2) concat
    ''-'' concat substr(digits(date),7,2))) as month
from ....
```

The key here is to convert it to character, then substring and insert the proper date separator character.

Then do it all over again for the GROUP BY.  It will be the most hideous SQL statement ever, but it'll be all client side.

Comment: Upvoting for persistence. I don't have the patience to verify for myself that this works, but I'll assume that something along these lines will work somehow. Given the OP's situation, and that he said he was looking for something, anything....

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark:  Have you tried using `INT` to force the data to be an integer?  As in `INT(INVOICE_DATE/100)`?

Other "spellings" of this might be `INTEGER(INVOICE_DATE/100)` or `CAST(INVOICE_DATE/100 AS INTEGER)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the syntax for the rollup.  Check the [documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059215.html) . .  .  The expression `group by rollup` works only with all the columns.  So, try this:

```
Group By ROLLUP (COMPETITOR_NAME,
    INVOICE_DATE/100,
    OVERRIDE_TYPE,
    CUSTOMER_NUMBER)
```

Or use grouping sets for different combinations.

Also, I suggest that you explicitly use integer division.  So, replace `\` with `idiv`:

```
invoice_date idiv 100
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's not the Rollup because that was also working before I added in the division.  Plus, I just moved the Rollup around and it didn't fix it, so...  On top of this, when I use idiv I am being told that the `100` toke was not valid.  It expects a `,FROM INTO`.